# Azure site recovery vs azure storage replication

Tags: azure-storage, azure-site-recovery

Why do we need Azure site recovery when we have azure storage replication? One point that I understood is that you can manually failover in case of azure site recovery. Doesn't Azure storage replication replicate all kind of data including VHD?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Azure Storage Replication: It is specifically for Azure Storage (data stored on storage) E.g vhds), it copies your data so that it is protected from planned and unplanned events ranging from transient hardware failures, network or power outages, massive natural disasters, and so on. You can choose to replicate your data within the same data center, across zonal data centers within the same region, and even across regions.

Whereas Azure Site Recovery contributes to your business continuity and disaster recovery (BCDR) strategy, by orchestrating and automating replication of Azure VMs between regions, on-premises virtual machines and physical servers to Azure, and on-premises machines to a secondary datacenter.

What can Site Recovery protect?

- Azure VMs: Site Recovery can replicate any workload running on a
  supported Azure VM.

  Hyper-V virtual machines: Site Recovery can protect any workload
  running on a Hyper-V VM.

  Physical servers: Site Recovery can protect physical servers running
  Windows or Linux.

  VMware virtual machines: Site Recovery can protect any workload
  running in a VMware VM.

What workloads can I protect with Site Recovery?
You can use Site Recovery to protect most workloads running on a supported VM or physical server. Site Recovery provides support for application-aware replication, so that apps can be recovered to an intelligent state. It integrates with Microsoft applications such as SharePoint, Exchange, Dynamics, SQL Server and Active Directory, and works closely with leading vendors, including Oracle, SAP, IBM and Red Hat. Learn more about workload protection.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-faq

Comment: Azure site recovery is recommend as a recovery service. That can use to migrate your on premises servers to Azure. When fail over that will create a server in Azure with on premises data disks.